# Unable to upgrade - slimerjs missing...?

Tags: node.js, npm, slimerjs

I'm running on OSX (El Capitan) with node v5.0.0 and npm v3.3.9.  if I attempt an upgrade:

```
npm upgrade
```

I get the error below:

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer
maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
"upgrade"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.9
npm ERR! code EREADFILE

npm ERR! Error extracting /Users/ekkis/.npm/slimerjs/0.9.5/package.tgz
archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/Users/ekkis/.npm/slimerjs/0.9.5/package.tgz'
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! [https://github.com/npm/npm/issues]

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!    /Users/ekkis/Downloads/client-side-testing-0.1/npm-debug.log
```

I've tried uninstalling this slimerjs (whatever that is) both locally and globally but it still fails.  if I look in the given directory there is indeed no 0.9.5 installed but I do find a 0.9.6

so what requires it and why isn't it satisfied with the later version? and most importantly, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

someone suggested 3.3.9 was rather behind the times.  upgrading (now v.3.5.2) seemed to solve the problem:

`sudo npm install -g npm`

Comment: This didn't work for me :-/ Still trying to understand the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known in the NPM project here - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10057. There's an issue with npm@3.x when installing packages having "latest" set to a pre release version.

My fix was to downgrade npm to 2.14.10 - the latest stable in the 2.x series since there was no fix yet posted.

`sudo npm install -g npm@2.14.10`

Answer (score 0):

for timebeing, Install specific version of slimmerjs eg. npm install slimerjs@0.9.5

https://github.com/graingert/slimerjs/issues/34